# Random choice from two match list [Python]

Tags: python, json, list, scripting, devops

I'm having issue to execute this scenario from my codes. I have to list inside .ini file.

```
[FMI]
vendorCodes=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
supplierName=["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5" ]
```

I used json.loads to call the list from the `.ini` file.

```
vendorCodes = json.loads(config.get('Section1','vendorCodes'))
supplierName = json.loads(config.get('Section1','supplierName'))4
```

From the list, the `random.choice` will execute to pick the data.

```
vendorCodes, supplierName = random.choice(vendorCodes), random.choice(supplierName)
```

I also have a function that will write it in the `.csv` file.

```
fmiwriter.writerow([poNumber] + [vendorCodes] + [supplierName])
```

Well the problem is the output is incorrect. It should match from the list, if the random choices from the vendorCodes is `a` then the `supplierName` should be `Test 1`.

Here is the incorrect output below:

```
588636,a,Test 3
332790,c,Test 2
810055,d,Test 4
655819,a,Test 3
159163,e,Test 1
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
588636,a,Test 1
332790,c,Test 3
810055,d,Test 4
655819,a,Test 1
159163,e,Test 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `choice`. Pick an integer index instead, and use that index to access both lists.

```
import random
index = random.randrange(len(vendorCodes))
chosenVendorCode = vendorCodes[index]
chosenSupplierName = supplierName[index]
```

Comment: I see. Using  an index is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the two lists for `random.choice` to pick a pair in tandem:

```
chosenVendorCode, chosenSupplierName = random.choice(zip(vendorCodes, supplierName))
```